# Using Realm with Diffable Data Source Section

Tags: swift, realm

I am having the following error whenever my snapshot is applied to my data source which I found out using breakpoints.

`reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: section != NSNotFound'`

I have an object called *Subject* and inside it, there is a list of *Mistake Categories* which are my sections. Within it, there is a list of *Mistakes* which are my items that I am trying to display.

However, it seems that I ran into a problem whenever I tried to apply my snapshot to my data source using my function *updateMistakesCollectionView()*.

```
private func updateMistakesCollectionView(){
        
        var snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<MistakeCategory, Mistake>()
        
        snapshot.appendSections(Array(subjectSelected.MistakeCategories))
        
        Array(subjectSelected.MistakeCategories).forEach{ category in
            snapshot.appendItems(Array(category.ChildMistakes), toSection: category)
        }
        
        mistakeDataSource.apply(snapshot)
        //crash
    }
```

My *viewDidLoad()* and *configureDataSource()* is as follows

```
private typealias mDataSource = UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<MistakeCategory, Mistake>
internal var subjectSelected:Subject!
private var mistakeDataSource:mDataSource!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //configure the data source
        mistakesCollectionView.register(DefaultCollectionViewReusableSectionView.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "DefaultCollectionViewReusableSectionView")
        configureMistakesViewControllerDataSource()
        //populate the data source
        updateMistakesCollectionView()
}

private func configureMistakesViewControllerDataSource(){
        
        //configure data
        mistakeDataSource = mDataSource(collectionView: mistakesCollectionView, cellProvider: {
            (collectionView, indexPath, mistake) in
            
            let cell = self.mistakesCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "mistakeCell", for: indexPath) as! MistakeCollectionViewCell
            
            cell.setProperties(mistake)
            
            print("Data Source Created!")
            return cell
        })
        
        //configure section headers
        mistakeDataSource.supplementaryViewProvider = { (collectionview, kind, indexpath) in
            
            guard kind == UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader else{
                return nil
            }
            
            let view = self.mistakesCollectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "DefaultCollectionViewReusableSectionView", for: indexpath) as! DefaultCollectionViewReusableSectionView
            
            let section = self.mistakeDataSource.snapshot().sectionIdentifiers[indexpath.section]

            view.setProperties(category: section)
            return view
        }
        
    }
```

Here are my code for *Mistake Categories* and *Mistake*

```
class MistakeCategory:Object{
    
    //properties
    @objc dynamic var mistakeCategoryName:String = ""
    
    //relationships
    let ChildMistakes = List<Mistake>()
    let MotherSubject = LinkingObjects(fromType: Subject.self, property: "MistakeCategories")
}

class Mistake:Object{
    
    //properties
    @objc dynamic var mistakeName:String = ""
    @objc dynamic var mistakeNumberOfTimesCommited:Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var mistakeDescription:String?
    @objc dynamic var mistakeDate:Date?
    
    //relationships
    var Subjects = LinkingObjects(fromType: Subject.self, property: "Mistakes") //subject
    
    var Categories = LinkingObjects(fromType: MistakeCategory.self, property: "ChildMistakes") //mistake category
}
```

I have tried to search the web for similar problems, however, I could not find any questions with the same problem and error. I am completely lost as to what could be wrong. Appreciate any help!

Comment: In programming, var's should always be lower case `let ChildMistakes` should be `let childMistakes`. Capitalized names are for Classes and Structures. Also, Realm objects are [Live Updating](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/ios/objects/#live-object) - as soon as you cast them to Swift objects, they loose their connection to Realm. More importantly, Realm objects are also lazily loaded; meaning that don't really occupy memory until they are used. As soon as they are cast to a Swift Array (for example) ALL of the objects are loaded into memory and could very well overwhelm the device and crash.

Comment: As far as the error goes - it's a little vague and the code is somewhat hard to follow. I would suggest adding a few breakpoints in your code and stepping through it line by line. Inspect your vars until something isn't as expected. It think this line `snapshot.appendItems` is where I would start - ensure your sections are populated. If this `let ChildMistakes = List<Mistake>()` in your MistakeCategory is empty, it may be causing a problem.

Comment: @Jay Thank you for replying and giving me tips because I'm still new to programming in general. I did add more breakpoints and where it starts to crash is when I use the forEach loop to append the Mistakes into the the Category section. I tried to use ```DispatchQueue.main.async``` and it only showed me my section headers before crashing with the same error. I tested and checked that my ChildMistakes are populated and it is. I am still not sure what is wrong.

Comment: @Jay I have a similar view controller and it works perfectly with the same exact code. Except, the previous view controller that provides the _subjectSelected_ is **popped** instead of **pushing** this view controller where I am having a problem. My guess is that the collection view is not properly loaded but I'm not too sure.

Comment: There's no information in the question related to subjectSelected other than it's a var so it will be hard to tell what the issue is without additional clarification.